# Individual tree extraction

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, image, aerial-photography, dem

I would like to extract individual trees in ArcMap 10.1. I have 1.3 meter resolution DSM data created from aerial images. I used Crown Height Model to extract tree heights (as attached file), but I am stuck here. Is there any possibility to somehow extract highest points (single point for each tree) or delineate each tree based on their heights.

[image]